# Boost::Python Not Finding C++ Class in OSX

Tags: python, c++, macos, boost, boost-python

I'm porting an Application from Linux to OS X and the Boost::Python integration is failing at run time.

I'm exposing my C++ classes like so:

```
using namespace scarlet;

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(libscarlet) {
    using namespace boost::python;

    class_<VideoEngine, boost::noncopyable>("VideoEngine", no_init)
        .def("play", &VideoEngine::play)
        .def("pause", &VideoEngine::pause)
        .def("isPaused", &VideoEngine::isPaused)
        [...]
    ;
}
```

I'm importing the library like so:

```
try {
    boost::python::import("libscarlet");
} catch (boost::python::error_already_set & e) {
    PyErr_Print();
}
```

Then I'm inject an instance into the global Python namespace like so:

```
void VideoEngine::init() {
    [...]
    try {
        auto main_module = boost::python::import("__main__");
        auto main_namespace = main_module.attr("__dict__");
        main_namespace["engine"] = boost::python::object(boost::python::ptr(this));
    } catch (boost::python::error_already_set & e) {
        PyErr_Print();
    }
    [...]
}
```

It works great in Linux but in OS X an exception is thrown and `PyErr_Print()` returns `TypeError: No Python class registered for C++ class scarlet::VideoEngine`.

As far as I can tell the module works without issue when imported via the Python interpreter. It is difficult to test since it designed to be injected as a pre-constructed instance but the class and functions are present as shown below:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import libscarlet
>>> libscarlet.VideoEngine
<class 'libscarlet.VideoEngine'>
>>> libscarlet.VideoEngine.play
<unbound method VideoEngine.play>
```

Any ideas as to where the incompatibility lies?

**Edit:** <strike>I'm starting to think it might be related to multithreading since my OS X implementation uses a different threading structure, although all of the calls detailed here happen in the same thread. Could that be the cause of such an issue?</strike> Probably not the issue since it doesn't work in MS Windows in single-threaded mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this now.

It was caused entirely by Boost::Python being statically compiled and once I recompiled it as a shared library the problem went away entirely, on all platforms.

The lesson: don't compile boost statically. I'm pretty sure there are warnings against it and they should be heeded.